# Filter data in one column based on data in other column

Tags: excel, vlookup

How can I find duplicate records using their `Item Number` and copy/extract `Unit Price`?

[image: Item Number / Price example]

Comment: you want unit price when F and G matches, right? there is autofilter seen and question says arrange data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a vlookup to find when an item matches another item in a different column.  For your example, assuming that row 20 column F contains the item 52F233, use this formula for cell I20

```
=VLOOKUP(F20,$G$1:$H$1000,2,FALSE)
```

This will put the unit price in cell I20 when a match is found and #N/A otherwise.  You can paste this formula in the entire I column and it will show you when the match is found for each entry.  After that, you can sort the ones with a valid match and take the next action you need with the matched data, such as add to a different sheet.  The vlookup formula cna be used across multiple files.